# Cannot select some people from reviewer drop-down in gerrit

Tags: gerrit

I'm having trouble figuring out what is going on here. Suddenly I found out that users cannot add me as a reviewer on their changes. When clicking on the edit link to add reviewers, I simply do not show up as an option. Interestingly, it seems like none of the users in the Administrator group can be chosen either.

When removing myself as an Administrator, I can now be selected as a reviewer. But, at least for the time being, I need to be an administrator.

Is there a setting to control this? I cannot find any obvious permission setting. I've also tried ensuring that the Administrator group is visible to all registered users, and that didn't change anything either.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be that somebody added the Administrators group to the Service Users group, and service users are explicitly left out of the results of the suggest_reviewers REST endpoint.